# Storybook + Vite + Svelte + Typescript : Typescript not being processed in `*.stories.svelte`

Tags: typescript, svelte, storybook, vite

I have been setting up storybook with Vite, Svelte and Typescript. It basically works fine except the Typescript part in the stories. For some reason Typescript preprocessing is being ignored in my `*.stories.svelte` files (in the component files it works fine).

I keep getting errors like this:

```sh
[vite] Internal server error: Unexpected token
  Plugin: storybook-addon-svelte-csf
  File: C:/projects/personal/exif-renamer/src/ui/1_globals/theme/font.stories.svelte
  2:     import { Meta,Story,Template } from '@storybook/addon-svelte-csf';
  3:     import { css } from '~/ui/1_globals/core/css';
  4:     import type { FontType } from './font';
                     ^
  5:     import { font } from './font';
```

For a `*.stories.svelte` file that has a script tag like this:

```html
<script lang="ts">
    import { Meta,Story,Template } from '@storybook/addon-svelte-csf';
    import { css } from '~/ui/1_globals/core/css';
    import type { FontType } from './font';
    import { font } from './font';

    const cn = (type: FontType) => css`${font(type)}`;
</script>
```

My  `.storybook/main.js` (where I have tried to force svelte preprocessing):

```js
const { resolve } = require('path');
const { svelte } = require('@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte');
const { typescript: svelteTS } = require('svelte-preprocess');

module.exports = {
  stories: [resolve('src/**/*.stories.@(ts|svelte)')],
  addons: ['@storybook/addon-essentials', '@storybook/addon-svelte-csf'],
  core: {
    builder: 'storybook-builder-vite',
  },
  async viteFinal(config) {
    const { default: viteConfig } = await import('../vite.config.js');

    const svelteIndex = config.plugins.findIndex(
      ({ name }) => name === 'vite-plugin-svelte'
    );

    config.plugins[svelteIndex] = svelte({
      preprocess: [svelteTS()],
    });

    // customize the Vite config here
    config.resolve.alias = viteConfig.resolve.alias;

    // return the customized config
    return config;
  },
};
```

Any ideas why Typescript preprocessing is being ignored in my `.stories` files??

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add `svelteOptions` to your `.storybook/main.cjs` instead of patching in svelte support in `viteFinal`

```
svelteOptions: {
 preprocess: preprocess(), // or `preprocess: [svelteTS()]` in your case
},
```

That enables Typescript in both *.svelte and *.stories.svelte files.

Requires `storybook-builder-vite` version 0.1.16 or later.

It doesn't work with the webpack builder *yet*:
https://github.com/storybookjs/addon-svelte-csf/pull/41

Comment: If you take a look at my `.storybook/main.js` that I posted you can see that it is already there.

Comment: My bad, I didn't spot a `svelteOptions`, but now I see you're patching in the preprocess in the viteFinal step, I've tried that approach in my project to see if svelteOptions vs viteFinal made a difference, but they both worked. 

Comment: Created a fix for storybook-builder-vite: https://github.com/eirslett/storybook-builder-vite/pull/240

Comment: And a fix for when using the webpack builder https://github.com/storybookjs/addon-svelte-csf/pull/41

Comment: OK thanks I will check it out

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that this was an actual bug, which should have been corrected with the latest version of Vite.